# Using templates/includes in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

im 'developing' an application made using Spring Boot, i am not so sure how to manage templates.

I've tought two ways to do this:

**Using custom tags and returning the value of the HTML/JSP file as a String and use it**

Something like this

```html
<th:header></th:header>
<!-- This would be the header (The implementation of this tag in Java) -->

<body>
  Things that are not common


  <th:footer></th:footer>
  <!-- This would be the footer -->
</body>
```

**The other way could be using includes, but im not so sure how to do it...**

Not sure if theres another way of doing this using Spring. Hope that you could understand me.

Thanks you before hand :·).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use Thymeleaf. Then you can use

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head th:replace="common/header :: common-header" />

<body>

    <div th:replace="common/navbar :: common-navbar" />
    <your content here>
</body
</html>
```

Then you would have the common-header and common-navbar thymeleaf fragments in separate files like so (note the th:fragment in the common files. Also note that these files are under a common folder):

```
<head th:fragment="common-header">

<title>DevOps Buddy</title>

<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css}"
      rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />

<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link type="text/css" th:href="@{/css/styles.css}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"/>
```

And so

```
<div th:fragment="common-navbar" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a th:text="#{navbar.home.text}" href="/"></a></li>
                <li><a th:text="#{navbar.about.text}" href="/about"></a></li>
                <li><a th:text="#{navbar.contact.text}" href="/contact"></a></li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li th:if="${#authorization.expression('!isAuthenticated()')}">
                    <a th:href="@{/login}" th:text="#{navbar.login.text}" />
                </li>
                <li th:if="${#authorization.expression('isAuthenticated()')}">
                    <form id="f" th:action="@{/logout}" method="post" role="form" class="navbar-form">
                        <button type="submit" th:text="#{navbar.logout.text}" class="btn btn-primary" />
                    </form>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I hadn't hear about this.

Comment: You are welcome. I'm creating an online course to teach how to create a website from scratch using Spring Boot, Thymeleaf, Bootstrap, AWS and Stripe. In the course I show the above topics as well as much more. If you want, you can register your interest here: http://academy.devopsfolks.com/courses/startup-ready-web-skeleton-with-spring-boot-aws-and-stripe/ and you'll be notified when the course is open for enrolment.